# помощь по fancybox

Tags: bootstrap, fancybox

Всем привет. Нужно было сделать fancybox. использовал пример по этой  [ссылке](http://bayguzin.ru/main/skriptyi/slajderyi/gallery-fancybox-bootstrap.html). вставил свою картинку не работает. а со своими работает.
Первая картинка она со ссылке. Вторую я вставил
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вставил свою картинку не работает. а со своими работает - это как?

Comment: @soledar10 когда использовал эту ссылку http://bayguzin.ru/main/skriptyi/slajderyi/gallery-fancybox-bootstrap.html там были картинки и они работали. Теперь хотел поставить свои картинки вместо них не работает.  Если посмотреть на скрин 1-работает потому что картинки уже там была. во 2-ом я вставил свою

Comment: код покажите, скорее всего вы неверно путь указали

Answer (score 1):

странно.. у меня все работает. Скачал архив - запустил, в папку картинок свою закинул и норм. Может вы в

```
<div class="mosaicflow__item">
    <a class="fancyimage" rel="group" href="bootstrap3-image-gallery/test.jpg">
      <img src="bootstrap3-image-gallery/test.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>
```

не заменили название в тегах `<a href` и `<img = src`, а только в 1. Ну или делали за указанным примером и что-то упустили.. советую скачать архив и взять готовый код редактировать под свои нужды/вставить в свой проект.

Comment: у вас Windows или Ubuntu?

Comment: виндовс, но это не должно влиять на работу по идее. Может в настройке среды что-то не так

Comment: услышал про mode-in. Знаете про него

Comment: нет, запустил на убунте то же - у меня все заработало(дистрибутив из архива демки).. может чтото не подключили или используете другую версию какой-то библиотеки где что-то могли изменить. Хотя если работает демка у вас то чтото не верно указали или не туда  вставили картинку.. может формат картинки не подходит

Comment: jpeg и там и у меня

Comment: тоже норм работает..у меня такая ошибка возникла когда я в index.html неверно указал путь/название с расширением файла